# Global Styles, Colors, Constraints for all UI elements, views in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have a background in UX and UI development for web applications, using CSS/HTML/JavaScript. I am self learning Swift. My goal is to be able to create screen layouts for our iOS developers that they can consume to integrate all the back end coding to.

In our web projects, I would create CSS/HTML/Javascript to make static pages that they then would integrate with a back end framework. This proved very successful to keep the UI visually and interaction wise consistent.

**My main question:**
Is there a equal way in Swift to globally set colors, set spacing between elements, set layout grids, set colors for element states during user interaction(Swift's .normal, .highlighted, etc.) etc. like you do in CSS for a website?

Swift Extensions seems like the way to accomplish this. I have coded a few Extensions for the colors.

Also, UIAppearance seems like another way to accomplish this.

I have also found solutions on how to code Constraints on classes like UIButton, UILabel, and UIView but, those solutions apply to the single element created, not all elements across the entire application.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, you can parse and render HTML with CSS coming from your backend via Text Kit or DTCoreText.

Comment: This was not the question. The question is about applying styles to various Swift applications, same as a CSS stylesheet would.

Comment: I refuse to believe that I am so far out on a limb with this question that no one has any comments. Any collaboration or direction you could give would be greatly appreciated.